# How to specify log4j.xml with aync

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, log4j, tomcat8

My Tomcat `log4j.xml` has a dependency on graylog2 server.
Few days back, my graylog2 server down due to storage issue after that my Tomcat's stop responding in between production hour. Then I came to know my `log4j.xml` has sync method that store the log first to graylo console then catalina.
How to come out with this dependecy?